# .Net List ForEach Item

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, foreach

I have 2 objects:

```
public class ClassA
{
   public int Id
   public string name;

   public ClassB myObjectB;

}
public class ClassB
{
   public int Id
   public string name
}
```

Having 2 Lists for <ClassA>  <ClassB>
Some items from List1 match by Id with an item on List2... I want to set the objectB foreach item...

```
foreach(ClassA item in List1)
{
   ClassB obj = (from b in List2 where b.Id == item.Id select b).SingleOrDefault()
   if(obj != null)
   {
       item.myObjectB = obj; 
       ////////break;    <- ignore this
   }
}
```

This solution works for me, but I'm just wondering if there is a better way to do this, instead of Foreach

Thanks everyone for your help!!!

Comment: You should probably remove `break;` to make it work for each item of List1

Comment: That is really bad code. you could've done `List2.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Id == item.Id);` instead of all that query syntax nonsense with a select.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that a `foreach`, in this case, is actually the appropriate approach, as you're mutating your list.  You could potentially simplify your code a bit, however:

```
foreach(ClassA item in List1)
{
    item.myObjectB = List2.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == item.Id);
}
```

This will set the item every time, though it will be set to `null` if there is no match.  If you already have items in `myObjectB` and setting them to null is inappropriate, you could use:

```
foreach(ClassA item in List1)
{
    item.myObjectB = List2.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == item.Id) ?? item.myObjectB;
}
```

Comment: It looks like the OP is breaking after the first match, so perhaps he does not need a `foreach`?

Comment: Oh, when I was writing the simplified version of my code, I put the break there, but good catch, the break is not supposed to be there...

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Reed's answer.. You can actually do this in a one-liner, because a list has a ForEach method.

```
List1.ForEach(item => item.myObjectB = List2.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == item.Id) ?? item.myObjectB);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<ClassA> list1 = new List<ClassA>();
List<ClassB> list2 = new List<ClassB>();

list1.Add(new ClassA { Id = 2, name = "a2" });
list1.Add(new ClassA { Id = 3, name = "a3" });
list1.Add(new ClassA { Id = 4, name = "a4" });
list1.Add(new ClassA { Id = 5, name = "a5" });

list2.Add(new ClassB { Id = 1, name = "b1" });
list2.Add(new ClassB { Id = 2, name = "b2" });
list2.Add(new ClassB { Id = 4, name = "b4" });
list2.Add(new ClassB { Id = 5, name = "b5" });

// Goal is to set ClassA::myObjectB from List1 to 
// matching instance (if any) of ClassB from List2
var query = 
    from a in list1
    from b in list2
    where a.Id == b.Id
    select Tuple.Create(a, b);  
foreach (var element in query)
    element.Item1.myObjectB = element.Item2;
```

**Update**:

Or if you really don't want a for loop, I just realized you can use the fact that assignments return a value and at the same time make an entry in an obfuscated code contest :)

```
(from a in list1
 from b in list2
 where a.Id == b.Id
 select a.myObjectB = b).ToList();
```

**Update2**:

I just thought of an alternate approach - depending on your scenario, a lazy mechanism might work for you?

```
public class ClassA
{
   public int Id
   public string name;

   private ClassB myObjectB;
   public ClassB MyObjectB { 
      get { return myObjectB ?? (myObjectB = list2.FirstOrDefault(x => this.Id == x.Id)); } 
   }
}
```

Comment: keep in mind that you can use anonymous types with linq, and would be clearer than using a turple.

Comment: i personally feel that's debatable because in this kind of situation the anonymous type ends up having member names with redundant information - but I'm not saying your wrong, thats just thought I've had about it...

Answer (score 0):

With classes defined as follows:

```
class ClassA {
   public int Id { get; private set; }
   public string name { get; private set; }

   public ClassB myObjectB { get; set; }

   public ClassA(int pId, string pName) {
      Id = pId;
      name = pName;
   }
}

class ClassB {
   public int Id { get; private set; }
   public string name { get; private set; }

   public ClassB(int pId, string pName) {
      Id = pId;
      name = pName;
   }
}
```

You can do the following using the LINQ `Join` method:

```
var listA = new List<ClassA> {
   new ClassA(1, "OneA"),
   new ClassA(2, "TwoA"),
   new ClassA(3, "ThreeA")
};

var listB = new List<ClassB> {
   new ClassB(1, "OneB"),
   new ClassB(2, "TwoB"),
   new ClassB(4, "FourB")
};

listA
.Join(
   listB,
   itemA => itemA.Id,
   itemB => itemB.Id,
   (itemA, itemB) => new { ItemA = itemA, ItemB = itemB }
).ForEach(pair => pair.ItemA.myObjectB = pair.ItemB);

listA.ForEach(itemA => Console.WriteLine(
   "{0} maps to {1}",
   itemA == null
      ? "null"
      : itemA.name,
   (itemA == null || itemA.myObjectB == null)
      ? "null"
      : itemA.myObjectB.name
));
```

Output is:

```
OneA maps to OneB
TwoA maps to TwoB
ThreeA maps to null
```